# Has there been added more Feat of Strengths in Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

Other than the Feat of Strength for having collectors edition, are there any other feat of strength added to the game with Heart of the Swarm?

[image: HeartCore Devotion]

Comment: I think that all answers to this question can be umbrella'd into the linked duplicate. I'd post a bounty if you're interested in promoting the HotS specifc Feats.

Comment: @Hurda because the linked question should instead be edited to include future expansions as they arrive and answer updated or new answers added to the old question.